# Pandas: How to have multi index on both rows and columns of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to create a dataframe having multi-indexing on both rows and columns? (as the image below represents) 
**Note:** The Bold cells represent the index.

[image: Multi-index on both rows and columns]

Comment: Sure it's possible. Where did you stuck?

Comment: Could you show me one simple example please?

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your indexes names in tuples and then use `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples()`, as in:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


columns = [["A","B","C","D","E"],
           ["f8gh", "ht6k", "gf4h", "fs2e", "po9a"]
          ]

c_tuples = list(zip(*columns))
multi_columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(c_tuples)

index = [[11869, 14363, 29554, 34554, 52473, 62948], 
         [14414, 29806, 31109, 36081, 54936, 63887], 
         ["+", "-", "+", "-", "+", "+"],
         ["1L1", "7P", "02-11", "38A", "4P", "11P"]]

i_tuples = list(zip(*index))
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(i_tuples)


data = [10, 9,2,7,7,2,7,8,6,5,1,7,2,9,10,6,2,4,10,7,4,6,4,4,3,2,6,9,7,5]

pd.DataFrame(np.array(data).reshape((len(multi_index),len(multi_columns))), 
             index=multi_index,
             columns=multi_columns)
```

[image: Output]